# Force Windows to use pagefile

Tags: windows, pagefile

I would like to know if there is a way to instruct Windows to utilize a portion of the pagefile on demand. Like an API or something. I'm currently working on a monitoring system with a function to check the amount of pagefile being used. There are test machines that aren't busy so their pagefile isn't being used aggressively. I need a way to spike the pagefile usage for my automated tests.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just allocate and use memory, more than you have RAM and it is always forced to swap.  Requires a 64-bit program.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks I will try to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Pagefile is usually used when there is not enough free RAM available. 
So in order to create a spike in pagefile usage open something heavy like a browser with 100 tabs or so on.

Comment: I'm thinking something programmatically like an MS api. So far I haven't found anything though.